# How do I apply a Cassandra patch or perform a minor version upgrade?

Tags: cassandra

could you please let me know what is the process or steps to apply Cassandra patch such as Cassandra-17821 or doing a minor version upgrade such as 3.10.6 to 3.10.10?

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 1):

In Cassandra, there are no "patches" in the same way as other legacy software. All the minor versions are patch releases so the only way to "apply" them is by upgrading.

For Debian or CentOS/RHEL package installations, you need to use APT or YUM to update the Cassandra package in the same way that you would update Linux packages on your Linux distribution.

For [tarball installations](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html#tarball), you just need to unpack the tarball to replace the Cassandra binaries on the node and reconfigure it as appropriate. Cheers!